# How can I write React code to add and remove components within components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm somewhat new to javascript and react. Working on a personal project, and I'm trying to build functionality where a user can add and remove custom player configurations. At the moment, it seems the best way to do this is to have buttons to add and remove components as need.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import ButtonGroup from '@material-ui/core/ButtonGroup';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete'


function Stats({ allStats, editedStats, statPlayerKey, statKey }) {
  
  const removeStats = () => {
    const filteredStats = allStats.filter((stat) => stat.statKey !== statKey);
    editedStats(filteredStats);
  }

  return (
    <Grid containter>
      <Button onClick={removeStats}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </Button>
      <Grid item>
        {statPlayerKey} {statKey}
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  )
}

function Player({ allPlayers, editedPlayers, playerKey, name }) {

  const [stats, setStats] = useState([])

  const handleRemove = () => {
    const filteredPlayers = allPlayers.filter((player) => player.playerKey !== playerKey);
    editedPlayers(filteredPlayers);
  };

  const statsList = stats.map(({statKey, statPlayerKey}) => (
    <Container>
      <Stats 
        allStats={stats}
        statKey={statKey}
        statPlayerKey={statPlayerKey}
        editedStats={setStats}
      />
    </Container>
  ))

  const addStat = () => {
    setStats([...stats, {statPlayerKey: playerKey, statKey: uuid()}])
  }

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Button onClick={handleRemove}>
        <DeleteIcon />
      </Button>
      <Grid item>
        {playerKey} {name}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        {statsList}
      </Grid>
      <Button onClick={() => addStat()}>
        Add Stat
      </Button>
    </Grid>
  );
};


function TestApp() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState([
    {
      playerKey: uuid(),
      name: "Mario"
    },
    {
      playerKey: uuid(),
      name: "Luigi"
    },
    {
      playerKey: uuid(),
      name: "Toad"
    }
  ]);

  const addPlayer = () => {
    setPlayers([...players, {
      playerKey: uuid(),
      name: 'Bowser'
    }])
  }

  const playersList = players.map(({ playerKey, name }) => (
    <Container>
      <Player
        allPlayers={players}
        editedPlayers={setPlayers}
        playerKey={playerKey}
        name={name}
      />
    </Container>
  ));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Team Members ({players.length})</h1>
      <Container>{playersList}</Container>
      <Button onClick={addPlayer}>ADD</Button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default TestApp;
```

Side notes - I'm using uuid's at the moment to track what's happening. Not sure if I should be trying to call those in the remove functions or not. Sorry for the current lack of front end design, planning to use material-ui, but I'm waiting to design the rest until I can get the functionality working as intended.

What am I doing wrong? Components are added easily enough, but the remove functionality is buggy. If you add a stat component to a player component and delete that player component, it passes the stat component to the next player in the list. I'd like the delete player button to delete the stat component(s) associated with the as well. I'd also like to add components within the stat components, so I want to make sure I'm executing this "components within components" method as efficiently as possible.

Comment: Hey @adev just for confirmation you want to add and remove component or state?

Comment: @VarunKaklia, I think I'm wanting to add and remove components via add and remove buttons, but I'm fairly new to this and not 100% sure.

Comment: basically, when I remove a Player component, I need it to remove all of the Stats components that were inside the Player component. When deleting the outer component, I need all inner components to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove State Value not Component, For that you have to make one function regarding `removeState` after that you able to remove function and function contains array' value remove from your current array.

Please do like remove array value(object) from state using splice

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

in your case do like this :

```
removeState(e) {
  var array = [...this.state.people]; // make a separate copy of the array
  var index = array.indexOf(e.target.value)
  if (index !== -1) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({people: array});
  }
},
```

Comment: This is how it would be written for class based functions, right? If possible, can you help me understand how to do this using react hooks and functional components?